Limit the maximum number of answers for a question
I am organizing a vote: from my applications, I created a multiple choice grid with the names in the first column and the answers "yes" "no" and "abstention" in the 2nd/3rd/4th column.
Except that I have a limited number of places: I would therefore like to know how I can limit the number of answers in the 2nd column (the "yes")?
For example: https://forms.gle/pLMZ3n9rZLrvLeeC7
I have 6 candidates (NAME 1 -> NAME 6), so I can a priori vote "yes", "no", "abstention" for each of them.
Except that, at the end of my vote, I can only have 4 people elected: I must therefore limit to 4 the number of "yes" answers per person who answers the vote.
My question was considered a duplicate of this question:Setting maximum number of sign-ups in Google Forms
But my request is not about the number of respondents to the survey. My limit is about the number of times a single respondent in a single question can answer the same thing (in my example: I can only answer "yes" 4 times)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What is the logic for the rest of the options? Can you answer "no" to all? Or "abstain" to all?

@Blindspots yes, it is possible. The only constraint is on the number of "yes" because I cannot have more than 4 people elected

To let responders choose max four names, use four questions that each let them choose one name, like this:



Please cast your votes
Choose a different name in each row




My first vote goes to:
dropdown list of names ↓


My second vote goes to:
dropdown list of names ↓


My third vote goes to:
dropdown list of names ↓


My fourth vote goes to:
dropdown list of names ↓



To give people the option vote for less than four names, include options like "(I am not using my second vote)", "(I am not using my third vote)" and so on.
The sample form you show also lets responders vote "against" someone by clicking "Non". If you need to track those "Non"-votes, add another section that lets choose names they are against to cast those votes.

I can only have 4 people elected: I must therefore limit to 4 the number of "yes" answers per person who answers the vote

The number of votes each responder has does not need to be the same as the number of people that get elected. There are many voting systems. See Ranked voting and Electoral system.

I hadn't actually thought of this solution.
In addition, can we modify the content of a drop-down list according to the choice of the previous answer? For example, if I choose "NAME1" as my first vote, remove "NAME1" from the second vote so that I can't vote twice for the same candidate

Technically, that can be done in Google Forms, but it would be very cumbersome. Regarding your real-world problem, it's unclear why everyone should vote for four candidates instead of voting for just one. I'd recommend that you consider another voting system. See the links I shared. Please ask only one question per post.

"it's unclear why everyone should vote for four candidates instead of voting for just one": it's simply because the statutes of my association require it. People apply individually to occupy one of the 4 possible positions: I don't see where this seems impossible.
I'm going to create a new discussion to see how to try (if it's not really too complicated) to delete a person in a drop-down list
